# How to run a play list with sox?

Tags: sox

Is it possible to play a list of music files with sox?

It is possible to play a file by:

```
play song.mp3
```

I know I can create a batch file which includes all the files to run such as:

```
play song01.mp3
play song02.mp3
```

But I would like to know if there is a setting in sox that simplifies running a list of files.

Answer (score 4):

`play` does accept multiple files:

```
play song01.mp3 song02.mp3 song03.mp3 ...
play song*.mp3
```

SoX also supports two playlist file formats, [m3u](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) and [pls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLS_(file_format)). m3u in particular is easy to create, a text file with one filename per line is valid already. When you have such a playlist file, you can run

```
play favourites.m3u
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `play` only supports supplying one filename, and there's no "playlist" option. You could have something like `GNU find` generate a "playlist":

```
find . -name '*.mp3' -printf 'play %p\n' > cmdfile
```

Then run `cmdfile` with your command interpreter.

A better option for playing files and playlists from the command line, IMHO, is [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu).